# High rank vector bundle over surfaces (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I would like to find a reasonably concise reference for the following fact.

Let $E$ be an orientable vector bundle over a closed orientable surface $\Sigma$ with rank at least 3. Suppose the second Steifel-Whitney class of $E$ vanishes, then $E$ is a trivial bundle.

Is this in Milnor-Stasheff?

Comment: I don't know a reference, but this follows pretty immediately from the fact that $B\mathrm{Spin}(n)$, $n > 2$, is at least $2$-connected.